# How to return a object from supplysync without blocking the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I am trying to return a future object without blocking the main thread. In doing so i tried using supplyAsync method to run thread asynchrously but while using get() function to get the required object main thread is getting blocked

```
final CompletableFuture<RequiredObject> future =CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {`RequiredObject ro = new RequiredObject;
//some code
return ro;
},executor);

future.get(); //this blocks the main thread
```

Executor thread is blocking the main thread

Comment: Take a look at javadoc for this method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get-- . It always waits if job it's not yet processed when you call this method.

Comment: Why are you calling `get()`? You initial task description “to return a future object” does not contain any requirement to call `get()`. To return a future, use `return future;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [getNow(T valueIfAbsent)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#getNow-T-)

> Returns the result value (or throws any encountered exception) if completed, else returns the given valueIfAbsent.